# Can I add different conf file per directory on Nginx?

Tags: php, nginx, configuration, subdirectory

I want to add different configuration file(s) to different directories. For example:

```
root /var/www/root/html

location / {
    root /var/www/root/html
    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    include a.conf
    include phphandler.conf
}
location /dir1/ {
    root /var/www/dir1/html
    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    include b.conf
}
location /dir2/ {
    root /var/www/dir2/html
    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    include c.conf
    include phphandler.conf
}
```

So each directory has own .conf file (e.g. a.conf, b.conf) which contains their own php handling options, error handling options etc. and there is common conf file (phphandler.conf) which contains configuration that applies on all subdirectories.

Will this work? I want to seperate error pages and configuaration files for each subdirectories.

Also, will updating nginx restore /site-available/default to theit default configuation?

Comment: Did it work? I recommend trying it and sharing details on what didn't work so people can help troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to your question is yes it will be work, but don't do it in `location /`

in your main `nginx.conf` you have to write paths to include

for example now you have only one `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;`

just add another one `include /etc/nginx/yourdir/*;`

Comment: Thanks. I'm not adding this to nginx.conf, but in /sites-available/default and I'm going to symlink it to /sites-enabled/

Comment: Also, did you mean I should add full path to "include anything.conf"? And what does "just add another one include /etc/nginx/yourdir/*;" mean?

Comment: @SmartPencil yes, I mean to add full path